# mule : Query Orders in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, mule

I have a flow with Salesforce Connector with query as SELECT Id from 'Order'. I am getting the below error,

```
[MalformedQueryFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='MALFORMED_QUERY'
 exceptionMessage='
SELECT AccountId,Id FROM 'Order'
                        ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:25
unexpected token: 'Order''
 extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
]
 row='1'
 column='25'
]
]
```

Any ideas what went wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switched to NativeQueryLanguage from DataSense Query Language in Salesforce connector. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove the apostrophes.

`SELECT Id from Order`